# Numpy set data depending on logical array

Tags: python, numpy

I have a logical matrix like :

`ind = np.array([1,0,1])`

and a data matrix like :

```
data = np.array([[1,2,3],
                 [4,5,6],
                 [7,8,9]])
```

And I would like to do something like this (this is the way to do it in MATLAB) :

```
data[ind,:] = 0
```

In order to set all the row with logical value to 1 to a specific value.

```
np.array([[0,0,0],
          [4,5,6],
          [0,0,0]])
```

How can I do it in Python ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do the same in [numpy](/questions/tagged/numpy) but you need a boolean array (this is called [boolean indexing](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/user/basics.indexing.html#boolean-array-indexing)):

```
data[ind.astype(bool), :] = 0

# or
data[ind==1, :] = 0
```

*NB. you don't need to refer to the second axis, `data[ind.astype(bool)] = 0`/`data[ind==1] = 0` is enough.*

Updated `data`:

```
array([[0, 0, 0],
       [4, 5, 6],
       [0, 0, 0]])
```

Intermediate:

```
ind.astype(bool)
# array([ True, False,  True])
```

Answer (score 1):

`data[ind==1, :] = 0`  will do the job

`ind==1` creates an array of boolean, which you can use as indices: `[ True False  True]`

Comment: How is this different from mozway's answer?

Comment: I was writing my answer while he was writing his, he was just faster than me. Are we supposed to check other answers when we post?

Comment: I agree, this can happen, not worth a DV in any case ;)

Comment: No, it definitely happens. Especially since Mozway can be pretty quick with their answers. I just saw that there was a couple of minutes between the answers so I wasn't sure if you were trying to add something new. (And I do not know what DV stands for...) Though, I do recommend checking if any new answers have been added before posting. I've been beaten to the punch many times while writing my own answer.